# HDMI Display Stopped Working

Tags: nvidia, xorg, multiple-monitors, hdmi

It used to work, but it suddenly stopped working. (no display in monitor, monitor power led just keeps blinking)

System Logs: (Please tell if I need to add something more)

(Every command was run while the HDMI cable was connected to the Laptop (Dell Inspiron 14 7000) and the Monitor (Acer)

---

**`# uname -r`**

```
4.8.0-58-generic
```

---

**`# lshw -c video`**

```
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 02
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:280 memory:d4000000-d4ffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
  *-display
       description: 3D controller
       product: GM108M [GeForce 940MX]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:284 memory:d2000000-d2ffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:d3000000-d307ffff
```

---

**`get-edid | parse-edid`**

```
This is read-edid version 3.0.2. Prepare for some fun.
Attempting to use i2c interface
No EDID on bus 0
No EDID on bus 2
No EDID on bus 4
No EDID on bus 5
No EDID on bus 6
2 potential busses found: 1 3
Will scan through until the first EDID is found.
Pass a bus number as an option to this program to go only for that one.
256-byte EDID successfully retrieved from i2c bus 1
Looks like i2c was successful. Have a good day.
Checksum Correct

Section "Monitor"
        Identifier "R231"
        ModelName "R231"
        VendorName "ACR"
        # Monitor Manufactured week 36 of 2016
        # EDID version 1.3
        # Digital Display
        DisplaySize 510 290
        Gamma 2.20
        Option "DPMS" "true"
        Horizsync 31-75
        VertRefresh 56-75
        # Maximum pixel clock is 180MHz
        #Not giving standard mode: 1152x864, 75Hz
        #Not giving standard mode: 1280x1024, 60Hz
        #Not giving standard mode: 1280x720, 60Hz
        #Not giving standard mode: 1280x800, 60Hz
        #Not giving standard mode: 1440x900, 60Hz
        #Not giving standard mode: 1680x1050, 60Hz
        #Not giving standard mode: 1920x1080, 60Hz

        #Extension block found. Parsing...
        Modeline        "Mode 10" 148.50 1920 2008 2052 2200 1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync 
        Modeline        "Mode 0" 148.50 1920 2008 2052 2200 1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync 
        Modeline        "Mode 1" 148.500 1920 2008 2052 2200 1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync
        Modeline        "Mode 2" 25.200 640 656 752 800 480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync
        Modeline        "Mode 3" 27.027 720 736 798 858 480 489 495 525 -hsync -vsync
        Modeline        "Mode 4" 74.250 1280 1390 1420 1650 720 725 730 750 +hsync +vsync
        Modeline        "Mode 5" 27.000 720 732 796 864 576 581 586 625 -hsync -vsync
        Modeline        "Mode 6" 74.250 1280 1720 1760 1980 720 725 730 750 +hsync +vsync
        Modeline        "Mode 7" 148.500 1920 2448 2492 2640 1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync
        Modeline        "Mode 8" 74.250 1920 2008 2052 2200 1080 1082 1087 1125 +hsync +vsync interlace
        Modeline        "Mode 9" 74.250 1920 2448 2492 2640 1080 1082 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync interlace
        Modeline        "Mode 11" 74.25 1280 1390 1430 1650 720 725 730 750 +hsync +vsync 
        Modeline        "Mode 12" 27.00 720 736 798 858 480 489 495 525 -hsync -vsync 
        Modeline        "Mode 13" 25.18 640 648 744 800 480 482 484 525 -hsync -vsync 
        Option "PreferredMode" "Mode 10"
EndSection
```

---

**`dmesg | grep microcode`**

```
[    1.112196] microcode: sig=0x806e9, pf=0x80, revision=0x42
[    1.112258] microcode: Microcode Update Driver: v2.01 <tigran@aivazian.fsnet.co.uk>, Peter Oruba
```

**`cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf`**

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier "layout"
    Screen 0 "nvidia"
    Inactive "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "intel"
    Driver "modesetting"
    BusID "PCI:0@0:2:0"
    Option "AccelMethod" "None"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "intel"
    Device "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Driver "nvidia"
    BusID "PCI:1@0:0:0"
    Option "ConstrainCursor" "off"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Device "nvidia"
    Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" "on"
    Option "IgnoreDisplayDevices" "CRT"
EndSection
```

---

**`# xrandr`**

```
eDP-1-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 309mm x 174mm
   1920x1080     60.02*+  59.93    48.03  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   960x600       60.00  
   960x540       59.99  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   576x432       60.06  
   512x384       60.00  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   320x240       60.05  
DP-1-1 disconnected
```

Answer (score 0):

Its funny and unexplainable, but all I did to fix this was

- Create a modeline string using cvt, `$ cvt 1920 1080` (I knew the monitor resoultion)
- Edit `xorg.conf` and force the Modeline and told it to ignore the EDID info sent by monitor. (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/HDMI)

These steps broke my system when I restarted and it went to some sort of safe mode where I could edit my xorg.conf. This also brought the display on the external monitor back. After some fiddling with xorg.conf I was able to make the config right, boot back to normal mode, and replaced the modified config with the original one that I had backed up, and everything worked.